# Best way storing combinations of distribution data in database

Tags: mysql, algorithm

I need the best way of storing my clients 'distribution areas' to the DB.

Every product I sell has this properties :

- From State
- From City
- From Zip-code
- To State
- To City
- To Zip-code

My clients often give me lists of where are their distribution area they are willing to buy my products from.

Example of clients data gived :

> 1) from CA,FL,HI,AK to zip codes 91367,12345,54321,98765
>
> 2) from 11111,22222,33333 to 44444,55555,66666

The way I store the data in my database is as this :

I have a table containing :fromState,fromCity,fromZip,toState,toCity,toZip

The way I store the data is by creating all possible combination of the 'FROM' and 'TO' data and for the seocnd example I get the following rows:

[image]

The problem is, sometimes the data is too long that it takes up to millions of records on my database and i'm looking for a better way to store my clients distribution requirements and then to check if my product is within their area of distribution.

Thanks for any suggestions !

Comment: Could you please clarify the kinds of queries you'd like to be able to retrieve from the data.? You mentioned, "my product is within their area of distribution." But what does that specifically look like (what is the actual comparison being made, what does 'product' look like and how is it stored)? And what other queries if any do you need to support?

Comment: Hi gilad, i've mentioned that my product contain this properties : from state,from city,from zip,to state,to city,to zip. if my product for example has the values : FROM California,hollywood,91367 TO Florida,miami,33018 So I need to check if I have a row with those params in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the most space efficient way to achieve this would be to make three tables: `From`, `To`, and `Client`. The `From` table would be your from columns in your table with an additional column of `clientId`, your `To` table would be your to columns in your table with an additional column of `clientId`, your `Client` table would have a `clientId` and possibly the name of the client or other identifying marks. This would relate your froms and tos to your client rather than to eachother and have a FROM + TO + 1 storage, rather than a FROM * TO storage.

To handle a many-to-one or many-to-many relationship of `From` and `To` keep the proposed `From` and `To` table structures, but change the proposed `client` table to be a relation table, `FromtoTo` for sake of example. The `FromtoTo` table would have a column of `From` relation IDs and a column of `To` relation IDs. Your `clientId` columns in your `From` and `To` tables would change to these relation IDs. An example of structure is below:

```
From
zip|fromRelId
001|1
002|1
005|2

FromtoTo
fromRelId|toRelId
1        |1
1        |2
2        |3

To
zip|toRelId
007|1
008|2
010|2
012|3
```

Here, From request 1 matches to To requests 1 and 2, From request 2 matches to To request 3.

Comment: But sometimes the clients have multiple requests, not always all the 'FROM' goes to all the 'TO'.

Comment: You could change the `client` table to a `request` table. Regardless you just need to make another association. If it is common for one `FROM` to go to many `TO` or reverse, I can revise my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yes it is common.

Comment: Thanks, so far your idea is good and will work, i'm still waiting for more answers before i'll marks yours as the answer.